# Qt5 project not building with Xcode 7

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt, cmake

I am working on a Qt5.4 project with C++11 using Xcode 6.4 as IDE, built with CMake 3.3.1. Recently, OS X decided to update to Xcode 7.0 (7A220), and as a result.

I now get the following message every time I try to build.

> The run destination My Mac is not valid for  Running the scheme
>   'live'.

Any ideas how to make it work again? I have no other destinations to build to, and creating fresh schemes does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a little too quick on the trigger. Re-building with Cmake did the job.